# how to correctly use integration response mapping in aws api gateway to return different http codes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I can't seem to set my integration response for errors using the amazon api gateway

[image]

I added an integration response but it does not return the 400 error, instead it continues to return 200 response with

```
{
  "errorMessage": "foose",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:11:19)"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the Java, you need to **throw** an Exception. I made the mistake of trying to **return** the error information. The Lambda Error Regex parses the Exception message so if you throw this:

```
throw new Exception("Failed: Something bad happened!");
```

and replace your `foo.*` with `Failed: .*` it will use the 400 status code.

If you are using NodeJS, you can use `context.fail('Failed: Something bad happened!');` to get the same result

Comment: What is the equivalent for context.fail() in Python ?

Answer (score 0):

```
.*"Failed:".*
```

This is the correct syntax for Lambda Regex. 
Also, in nodeJS (as per your example above) it's easier to construct your own error object and add status for easier mapping, e.g.:

```
var myError = {}
myError.status = "userError"; //use this for 400 and "serverError" for 500
myError.message = err.stackTrace; //message body
```

Finally you need to return

`context.fail(JSON.stringify(myError));`

If you don't have response mapping set up properly.