# AWS API Gateway: Regex for error is not picked up

Tags: amazon-web-services, f#, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a Lambda function tied to the AWS API gateway. When I call it with something like `/foo/bar` and `bar` does not exist, my function returns (correctly) something like:

```
{
  "code": 404,
  "message": "bar not found"
}
```

I now want the status code of this to be 404, too, but following the tutorials I could find on the net, I had no success so far. What I did:

I created a method response for 404 that looks like this:
[image: 404 response]

And in the integration response, I set the following:
[image: 404 integration response]

To my understanding, this should set the code to 404 when `404` appears in the response document, but I still get `200`.

What am I missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47105287/6108211 I hope it helps

Comment: No, it didn't. I even tried to shape the output so it looks exactly like yours, and I still get 200. It seems that it doesn't pick up the regex. If I set the regex to .* (match all), it works, but as soon as I incorporate any other character, it is ignored.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I investigated some more and found out that the API gateway is very picky about where it expects its error messages, and how I have to get them out.

It is deeply buried and not easily found in [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-method-settings-execution-console.html) that the `errorMessage` property is considered for matching against the Lambda Error Regex, and the [first answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346577/how-to-correctly-use-integration-response-mapping-in-aws-api-gateway-to-return-d) states you have to throw an exception when using Java 8. I use .net for my Lambda function, so I did this very simple thing:

```
new Exception("404") |> raise
```

then I set up the Lambda Error Regex `404` and it worked.

Next thing I tried was:

```
new Exception("foo 404 bar") |> raise
```

With the regex `.*404.*` it still worked.

Now comes the thing: I tried to emit a JSON object as the error, but I found nothing in C# or F# to let me do this, so I came up with the following:

```
type Error = {
    code: int
    message: string
}

...

new Exception({ code = 404; message = name |> sprintf "%s not found" } |> JsonConvert.SerializeObject) |> raise
```

And boom, I got 200 again.

So I conclude from this, AWS doesn't like stringified JSON in the `errorMessage` property, so I now just output a simple string like this:

```
new Exception(name |> sprintf "404: %s not found") |> raise
```

and using the regex `404:.*`, it now works. That means, I somehow have to construct my desired output object using the mappings in the API gateway.

This is quite inconvenient and something easy to trip over...