# AWS Api Gateway response mapping regex not working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to do a mapping from AWS lambda function response using regex.
This is my regex:
`.*statusCode”:406.*`

As you can see - I am trying for it to take a specific mapping from the following response:

```
{
  "statusCode": 406,
  "body": "{\"aerocrs\":{\"success\":false,\"error_type\":\"request\",\"details\":{\"detail\":\"Incorrect reqyest \",\"errorCode\":4}}}",
  "headers": {
    "x-powered-by": "Express",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "content-length": "116",
    "etag": "W/\"74-Zzo6HU1M1kKkLM9KGtX0jJdePQY\"",
    "date": "Thu, 28 Nov 2019 16:03:05 GMT",
    "connection": "close"
  },
  "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

However, I always get to the default mapping.
When I change the mapping to `.*.*`, it gets to the correct one, which makes sense, but for some reason this regex isn't working.
Do you have any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Formatting ruined everything. The regex is .*statusCode”:406.*

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the issue!
Thanks to [this great person.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498940/aws-api-gateway-regex-for-error-is-not-picked-up%20as%20the%20answer.)

Long story short. AWS Api Gateway is SUPER picky and annoying regarding the error regex. This means, that is looking for a specific structure. Something of this sort:

```
{
  "errorType": "string",
  "errorMessage": "{\"body\":{\"success\":false,\"error_type\":\"request\",\"details\":{\"errorCode\":4}}}",
  "trace": []
}
```

So the `.*.*` does work because it is valid for everything, but even a single letter, like `.*s.*` is causing an issue.
What you need to fix is in your lambda function.
In my case - I was using nodeJS function, and aws-serverless-express.
The aws-serverless-express is super easy as it works perfectly with express. However, I was using:

```
awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context);
```

Which was enough to return the response ok, but not enough to work with the API gateway's annoying regex.
Instead, I changed it to this:

```
awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context, 'CALLBACK', function(param1, response){
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        //Success
        context.done(response.body);
    }
    else {
        //Fail
        context.fail(response.body);
    }
});
```

And it worked like a charm. Now I took the response body and return it as success / fail. Then it will work with the format that the lambda function knows how to use.

I hope this will help other people not waste 6 hours on this!

Answer (score 0):

looks like the output has a space before 406. what happens if you add that space to your regex?

--Edited to add: I use this site all the time (with redacted stuff, naturally) - https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks! But it also didn't work, I tried even to just put .*statusCode*. and it still doesn't recognise it.
I have also tried in the site you gave - and it's working. It's something in the gateway I think.
Here are screen shots:
https://prnt.sc/q3r9l2 and https://prnt.sc/q3r9zo and https://prnt.sc/q3rahx